# Why does this table sort all entries as strings?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have the problem that the JTable that I fill myself with data and want to autosort it using the interface. However it gets sorted as Strings, so 10 comes after 2. How can i fix that?

```
public class GUI extends Frame implements ActionListener, WindowListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -693036000167528691L;
    private Button run,findAll,sortByNumberOfStretchesFound, sortByLongestStretch;
    private TextField selectionSizeStart, numberOfThreads, selectionSizeEnd, minimumStretchSize, sequence;
    private JTable table;
    private String[] columnNames = new String[]{"#","Label","Label-Length","#Stretches Found","Unique","Longest Stretch"};
    private int sortBy = 3;
    private Object[][] data;

    public GUI(String defaultSequence, int defaultSelectionMinimumSize, int defaultNumberOfThreads) {
        table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,0));

        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        JScrollPane scrollbar = new JScrollPane(table);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: In Strings, 10 comes **before** 2.

Comment: I would discourage you from mixing AWT and Swing components

Comment: How else would it sort `Object`s? How do you expect it to compare an `Integer` to a `String` to a `MyRandomDto`? Set a custom `RowSorter`.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565262/sorting-different-data-types-using-setautocreaterowsorter-in-jtable

Comment: Put an Integer in numerical columns.

Comment: how do i designate an integer column ?

Comment: @bmorris591 Extend that comment and make it answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the javadocs for [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoCreateRowSorter%28boolean%29); the `setAutoCreateRowSorter` creates instances of [`TableRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) and from it's javadoc sorting works as follows

1. If a `Comparator` has been specified for the column by the `setComparator` method, use it.
2. If the column class as returned by `getColumnClass` is `String`, use the `Comparator` returned by `Collator.getInstance()`.
3. If the column class implements `Comparable`, use a `Comparator` that invokes the `compareTo` method.
4. If a `TableStringConverter` has been specified, use it to convert the values to `String`s and then use the `Comparator` returned by `Collator.getInstance()`.
5. Otherwise use the `Comparator` returned by `Collator.getInstance()` on the results from calling `toString` on the objects.

So if you want to change the default (5 in this case) you need to either

1. Set a `Comparator`,
2. Implemenet `Comparable<SomeCommonInterface>` in your data objects or
3. Set a `TableStringConverter` to implement custom `toString` functionality

Alternatively you could skip all that and implement a custom [`RowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) with your own custom sorting logic.

**EDIT**

From the OP's comments there is a mixed array of `Integer` and `String`.

There is no obvious way to compare a `Integer` to a `String` so you would need to decide on a rule, I will assume that rule is "number before string".

Now, either wrap all your data in a class that implements `Comparable` on `Object` and do your work there or implement a `Comparator<Object>`, set it on the table. In the compare method you would need to use `instaceof` to work out what you're comparing and compare them. The method would need to look something like:

```
class MyClass implements Comparator<Object> {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (o1 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o2 == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o1 instanceof Integer && o2 instanceof String) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o1 instanceof String && o2 instanceof Integer) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o1 instanceof Integer && o2 instanceof Integer) {
            return ((Integer) o1).compareTo((Integer) o2);
        }
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i set a comparator? What is the easiest way to just sort the table by numbers, if it contains numbers?

Comment: 1) read the javadoc that I linked to. 2) use a `Integer[][]` or whatever rather than the `Object[][]` that you currently have and it will work automagically.

Comment: what if i have a mixed array? Part of the array data which is Object[][] is string, part of it is integer.

Comment: Added an example in my answer.